# is global counter thread safe in python?

Tags: python

```python
import threading
import time


counter = 0

def increase(name):
    global counter
    i = 0
    while i < 30:
        # this for loop is for consuming cpu
        for x in xrange(100000):
            1+1
        counter += 1
        print name + " " + str(counter)
        i += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    try:
        for i in xrange(100):
           name = "Thread-" + str(i)
           t = threading.Thread( target=increase, args=(name,) )
           t.start()
           threads.append(t)
    except:
          print "Error: unable to start thread"

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

Python version is 2.7.5.

For the above code, I run it several times, the final result is always 3000.

And this code is also the example of this blog.
http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

But this blog also mentions that:

> In general, this approach only works if the shared resource consists of a single instance of a core data type, such as a string variable, a number, or a list or dictionary. Here are some thread-safe operations:
>
> - reading or replacing a single instance attribute
> - reading or replacing a single global variable
> - fetching an item from a list
> - modifying a list in place (e.g. adding an item using append)
> - fetching an item from a dictionary
> - modifying a dictionary in place (e.g. adding an item, or calling the clear method)

This confuses me that, do we really need lock to get the correct result with multi-threading in python?

**Update 1**

My Linux distro is `CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511`, kernel version is `3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 30 12:09:22 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

And my mac is version 10.11.5 (15F34), python version is 2.7.10.

I run the program on my Mac, the result is expected, the counter does not equal to the expected, due to the usage of un-thread-safe global counter.

But when I ran the program on my Linux, the result always equals to the expected value.

```
counter:3000, expected:3000
counter:3000, expected:3000
counter:3000, expected:3000
counter:3000, expected:3000
counter:3000, expected:3000
```

Do I miss something here which can cause the difference?

**Update 2**

Another observation is that the linux box i use above has only one core. When I switch to another linux box which has 4 cores, the result is expected.

According to my understanding of Python GIL, it guarantees that the programs will alway run on a single core, no matter how many cores the platform has. But the GIL will not guarantee the safety between different threads right?

If this holds, why the single core machine gives such result?

Thanks.

Comment: CPython has a global interpreter lock, meaning only on thread runs at a time. https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann: it's not exactly like that; only one thread runs *Python bytecode* at a time; preempting "between opcodes" is allowed, hence you can have race conditions even in Python.

Comment: Definitely not safe: I get results around 2995...

Answer (score 10):

It's not safe, even in CPython. Although the GIL protects a single opcode execution, a `+=` is actually expanded to several instructions:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> counter = 0
>>> def inc():
...     global counter
...     counter += 1
... 
>>> dis.dis(inc)
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (counter)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 INPLACE_ADD         
              7 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (counter)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

The code here loads `counter` on the stack, increments it and stores it back; thus, there is a race condition between LOAD_GLOBAL and the STORE_GLOBAL. Let's imagine that two threads running `inc` get preempted as follows:

```
Thread 1                Thread 2
LOAD_GLOBAL 0
LOAD_CONST 1
INPLACE_ADD
                        LOAD_GLOBAL 0
                        LOAD_CONST 1
                        INPLACE_ADD
                        STORE_GLOBAL 0
STORE_GLOBAL 0
LOAD_CONST 0
RETURN_VALUE
                        LOAD_CONST 0
                        RETURN_VALUE
```

Here the increment done by thread 2 gets lost completely, since thread 1 overwrites `counter` with his incremented stale value.

You can easily verify this yourself removing much of the waste of times in your code and make them "race hard":

```
import threading
import time

counter = 0
loops_per_increment = 10000

def increment(name):
    global counter
    i = 0
    while i < loops_per_increment:
        counter += 1
        i += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    expected = 0
    threads = []
    try:
        for i in xrange(100):
           name = "Thread-" + str(i)
           t = threading.Thread( target=increment, args=(name,) )
           expected += loops_per_increment
           t.start()
           threads.append(t)
    except:
          print "Error: unable to start thread"

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    print counter, "- expected:", expected
```

Here's some numbers I get on my 8-core machine:

```
[mitalia@mitalia ~/scratch]$ for i in (seq 10)
                                 python inc.py 
                             end
47012 - expected: 1000000
65696 - expected: 1000000
51456 - expected: 1000000
44628 - expected: 1000000
52087 - expected: 1000000
50812 - expected: 1000000
53277 - expected: 1000000
49652 - expected: 1000000
73703 - expected: 1000000
53902 - expected: 1000000
```

Comment: Italia, Thanks for your answer and your for loop is what is expected. I ran your modified program on my Mac 10.11.5 (15F34), which has Python 2.7.10. The result is that same as yours. But when I ran it on my linux box, the counter always equals to the expected value 1000000, which I don't know how to explain. Do you know some configuration that makes it behaves different on Linux?  My linux version is 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 30 12:09:22 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: see my updates, there is only one core in my Linux box

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import sys
# Check for thread switches after every virtual instruction.
sys.setcheckinterval(0)

import threading

INCREMENTS = 1000000

counter = 0

def task():
  global counter
  for i in xrange(INCREMENTS):
    counter += 1

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=task)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=task)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()

print "expected counter:", INCREMENTS * 2, "final counter:", counter
```

Comment: This program runs as expected even on the single core linux box. I checked my python's checkinterval through `sys.getcheckinterval()`, it's default to 100. event on the four-core linux box. So why do they have such different behavior?

Comment: @Alex setting a lower check interval increments the probability of two or more threads reach the same non-atomic instruction "at same time". For example `counter += 1` expands into three python virtual instructions like @MatteoItalia said. In this specific case the key is at the python virtual instruction `INPLACE_ADD`, that is, if two threads execute `INPLACE_ADD` "at same time" then the `counter` will be incremented only once. And the reason because your example has not showed until now the race condition is only matter of probabilities or luck due to the default `100` virtual instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I revisited the talk on GIL of David M Beazley.

According to his talk, there is less thread context switches on single core CPU.

Here is what he found:

http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL/gilvis/linuxonecpu.html
http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL/gilvis/fourthread.html

I conclude from his post that, there will be more frequent thread context switch on a multi core system; i.e. the less core you have, the bigger your system check interval will be.

If this finding holds, then it can explain why my multiple thread test above always get the correct result on a single core Linux.