# Do we ever need to synchronise threads in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, cpython, gil

According to GIL wiki it states that

`In CPython, the global interpreter lock, or GIL, is a mutex that prevents multiple native threads from executing Python bytecodes at once. This lock is necessary mainly because CPython's memory management is not thread-safe.`

When multiple threads tries to do some operation on a shared variable at same time we need to synchronise the threads to avoid Race Conditions. We achieve this by acquiring a lock.

But since python uses GIL only one thread is allowed to execute python's byte code, so this problem should be never faced in case of python programs - is what I thought :( .But I saw an article about thread synchronisation in python where we have a code snippet that is causing race conditions.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-python-set-2-synchronization/

Can someone please explain me how this is possible?

**Code**

```
import threading

# global variable x
x = 0

def increment():
    """
    function to increment global variable x
    """
    global x
    x += 1

def thread_task():
    """
    task for thread
    calls increment function 100000 times.
    """
    for _ in range(100000):
        increment()

def main_task():
    global x
    # setting global variable x as 0
    x = 0

    # creating threads
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_task)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_task)

    # start threads
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    # wait until threads finish their job
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        main_task()
        print("Iteration {0}: x = {1}".format(i,x))
```

**Output:**

```
Iteration 0: x = 175005
Iteration 1: x = 200000
Iteration 2: x = 200000
Iteration 3: x = 169432
Iteration 4: x = 153316
Iteration 5: x = 200000
Iteration 6: x = 167322
Iteration 7: x = 200000
Iteration 8: x = 169917
Iteration 9: x = 153589
```

Comment: read: https://www.backblaze.com/blog/the-python-gil-past-present-and-future/

Comment: that's because you are using a foreign site as a source of information instead of official python sites, if you actually ran the code snippet you'll only get the same result of `200000` on all tries due to the gil, please avoid taking information from foreign tutorial sites as facts, python object are thread safe. (unless you modify them without having the gil in some weirdly buggy C extension).

Comment: Although the GIL allows access to memory in a threadsafe way, you still have other concerns. The issue here is atomicity. The processes of obtaining the variable, incrementing it, and then re-assigning it are three discrete steps. A multithreaded program may interleave these operations between multiple threads in many different orders. To avoid this issue, the group of actions must become atomic. One thread needs to be able to perform all of these actions at once without any other threads acting on the variable while it is in an intermediary state. This is usually done with locks.

Comment: @flakes again my doubt here will be when a thread is performing one of these actions how can other thread act on the variable? Because it will be waiting for GIL to be released right

Comment: @AhmedAEK IIUC `+=` is performed using multiple instructions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990533/is-global-counter-thread-safe-in-python

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717393/is-the-operator-thread-safe-in-python

Comment: @flakes i have ran that code on all python 3.7 to 3.10 interpreters and they all consistently give the correct result, so i am guessing that was an an issue in python 2 or at least some version of it.

Comment: @flakes thanks for sharing, so it depends on the operation that we are performing on variable?

Comment: @AhmedAEK Id say this is probably some optimization in the cpython implementation and how GIL is being scheduled for release, and not something to rely on. Changes to bytecode in the future could change the typical behavior.

Comment: @AhmedAEK, FYI, When I run it in Python 3.9.6 on a Macintosh computer with an Apple M1 CPU and MacOS 12.6, it prints 200000 about 80% of the time, and smaller numbers the rest of the time. As far as I know, what I see is considered to be acceptable behavior for Python, and what you see also is considered to be acceptable behavior. Most programming language standards only promise that correctly written multi-threaded programs will give predictable answers. They do _not_ promise that _badly_ written multi-threaded programs will give _unpredictable_ answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one thread at a time can execute bytecode. That ensures memory allocation, and primitive objects like lists, dicts and sets are always consistent without the need for any explicit control on the Python side of the code.

However, the `+= 1`, integers being imutable objects, is not atomic: it fetches the previous value in the same variable, creates (or gets a reference to) a new object, which is the result of the operation, and then stores that value in the original global variable. The bytecode for that can be seen with the help of the `dis` module:

```
In [2]: import dis

In [3]: global counter

In [4]: counter = 0

In [5]: def inc():
   ...:     global counter
   ...:     counter += 1
   ...: 

In [6]: dis.dis(inc)
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  3           2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (counter)
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             16 BINARY_OP               13 (+=)
             20 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (counter)
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

And the running thread can change arbitrarily between each of these bytecode instructions.

So, for this kind of concurrency, one has to resort to, as in lower level code, to a lock -the `inc` function should be like this:

```
  In [7]: from threading import Lock

In [8]: inc_lock = Lock()

In [9]: def inc():
   ...:     global counter
   ...:     with inc_lock:
   ...:         counter += 1
   ...:
```

So, this will ensure no other thread will run bytecode while performing the whole `counter += 1` part.

(The disassemble here would be significantly lengthier, but it has to do with the semantics of the `with` block, not with the lock, so, not related to the problem we are looking at. The lock can be acquired through other means as well - a `with` block is just the most convenient.)

Also, this is one of the greatest advantages of async code when compared to threaded parallelism: in async code one's Python code will always run without being interrupted unless there is an explicit deferring of the flow to the controlling loop - by using an `await` or one of the various `async <command>` patterns.

Answer (score 1):

> since python uses GIL only one thread is allowed to execute python's byte code

All of the threads in a Python program must be able to execute byte codes, but at any one moment in time, only one thread can have a lock on the GIL. The threads in a program continually take turns locking and unlocking it as needed.

> When multiple threads tries to do some operation on a shared variable at same time we need to synchronise the threads to avoid Race Conditions.

"Race condition" is kind of a low-level idea. There is a higher-level way to understand why we need mutexes.

Threads communicate through shared variables. Imagine, we're selling seats to a show in a theater. We've got a list of seats that already have been sold, and we've got a list of seats that still are available, and we've got some number of pending transactions which have seats "on-hold." At any given instant in time, if we count all of the seats in all of those different places, they'd better add up to the number of seats in the theater—a constant number.

Computer scientists call that property an *invariant.* The number of seats in the theater never varies, and we always want all the seats that we know about to add up to that number.

The problem is, how can you sell a seat without *breaking* the invariant? You *can't.* You can't write code that moves a seat from one category to another in a single, atomic operation. Computer hardware doesn't have an operation for that. We have to use a *sequence* of simpler operations to move some object from one list to another. And, if one thread tries to count the seats while some other thread is half-way done performing that sequence, then the first thread will get the wrong number of seats. The invariant is "broken."

Mutexes solve the problem. If every thread that can temporarily break the invariant only ever does it while keeping a certain mutex locked, and if every other thread that cares about the invariant only ever checks it while keeping the same mutex locked, then no thread will ever see the broken invariant other than the one thread that is doing it on purpose.

You can talk about "invariants," or you can talk about "race conditions," but which feels right, depends on the complexity of the program. If it's a complicated system, then it often makes sense to describe the need for a mutex at a high level—by describing the invariant that the mutex protects. If it's a really simple problem (e.g., like incrementing a counter) then it feels better to talk about the "race condition" that the mutex averts. But they're really just two different ways of thinking about the same thing.